# Fastest and most efficient way to search an XML string in Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-parsing

I am working with old legacy code and need an efficient way to search xml and assign it to an object.

This is what xml would look like

```
<Accounts>
  <AccountNumber>12345</AccountNumber>
  <FirstName>John</FirstName>
  <LastName>Peter</LastName>
  <Address>123 somwhere st</Address>
<Accounts>
<Accounts>
  <AccountNumber>8734</AccountNumber>
  <FirstName>Johnson</FirstName>
  <LastName>Peterson</LastName>
  <Address>456 somwhere st</Address>
<Accounts>
```

I have over 500 elements of accounts. What I need is to search for the AccountNumber and assign the data from that account to an object.

```
for(int i = 0; i < requestedAccounts.Count; i++)
{
  var foundAccount = xmlReader.Where(x => x.Account == requestedAccounts[i].AccountNumber); 
var FirstName = foundAccount.FirstName;

}
```

I need something similar to this that works and is very fast.

Ive tried xmlreader, directy looping through each node both are not fast enough.
The current method loops through each node in the xml to find the account so on every loop it is looping through over 500 elements. This takes too much time.

Ive also looked on stackoverflow but all of the answers are from 2011. That was over 10 years ago so I was hoping there was a more updated answer.

Comment: Step 1) Put the account ids you want to find in a hashset. Step 2) Read through the XML checking if the account id for that node is in the hashset. If it is, do whatever you need to. Step 3) Remove the item from the hashset. Step 4) Move on to the next node if the hashset isn't empty.

Comment: Try using `XElement`. `foreach(XElement e in root.Elements) if (e.Element("AccountNumber").Value == x) var o = e.ToObject()` <-- `ToObject` extension to convert element to the object you want. I found this working really fast

Comment: Have a look at the XDocument class, you can associate it with XPath expressions and it heavily uses Linq. It probably is faster than than using XmlReader, and definitely easier to use.